# Drag and drop with Alt + Tab

Tags: 18.04, gnome, interface

On Linux Mint, I remember I was able to initiate a drag and drop operation from one application, press Alt-Tab to switch to another application, and finalize the drop. This allows me to easily transfer items from one app to another even if the apps are fullscreen.

In Ubuntu 18.04, I find that Alt-Tab does not work when I initiate the drag operation (i.e., with the click held).

Is there any workaround for this? Any setting I can tweak?

Note that there are some older versions of this question on this forum, but I'm not sure they apply anymore since in 18.04 Ubuntu switched back to the GNOME desktop.

Comment: My guess is this *feature* is more related to the desktop (GUI) in use, and not the OS (be it Mint or Ubuntu).  What DE are you comparing GNOME to?

Comment: @guiverc In Linux Mint I was using the default (Cinnamon)

Comment: I am afraid this indeed does not work in Gnome Shell. The "official" way in pure Gnome Shell would be to drag to activities hotcorner, then in activities overview, drag to the target window. Alas, in Ubuntu, the hotcorner is disabled. Allegedly, you need to travel a long distance this way.